# How Python imports an instance of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find out how exactly importing works in Python.
Let's say I have a `foo.py` module that contains the following class:

```
class Foo: 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        ... 


foo = Foo()
```

Now, I want to import it in other modules.

Is it going to use the same instance every time that I import it or will make different instances whenever I import it and is it even a good way to instantiate a class or it'd be better to import the `Foo` class and create an instance in modules that imported it(As it's obvious, this class doesn't need any args and kwargs).

Comment: Importing is very simple. It just runs the script and makes all the global variables that are defined available in the importer. If you say "from module import <names>" just those names are made available.

Comment: If you import a script multiple times in the same python invocation, it only runs it once. So there will only be one `foo`.

Comment: All uses of `modulename.foo` will refer to the same instance.

Comment: it's usually poor design to depend on global variables from a module, except for things like enums that are just giving labels to simple values. If you want there to be just one `Foo()` instance, use the Singleton pattern.

Comment: The `logging` module maintains a single instance of `RootLogger` as a module global (though the documentation only mentions accessing it with `getLogger`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import it in the usual way:
`from foo import Foo`

If this is the first time, the foo.py code will execute and the {`class`, `def`} statements will generate bytecode for the interpreter.
And we make a note of it in `sys.modules`.

Subsequent imports will benefit from a cache hit, so we won’t repeat all that evaluation work.
When baz.py and qux.py ask for an import of the `foo` module,
they will immediately obtain the cached result,
which contains that same old `Foo` class bytecode.

Bottom line: you get exactly one instance of the code in that class.

Comment: FYI: `sys.modules` is a dictionary containing imported module names and references.